# Java Random giving negative numbers

Tags: java, random

I'm having trouble with Javas `Random` class, if i do this:

```
Random rng = new Random(seed) // seed == 29 in this example

String ss = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int s = rng.nextInt();
            ss += Integer.toString(s);
            ss +="\n";
        }
```

This is what i get back:

```
-1169335537
-2076183625
1478047223
1914482305
722089687
2094672350
-1234724057
-1614953544
-321574001
1000360613
```

From what I have read this should only be returning positive numbers for a start?

This may be a bit far fetched but it couldnt have anything to do with running a 64 bit machine on Windows 7 64 bit?

Any help at all would be awesome need to get this finished for an assignment hand in today!

Comment: only believe what you read in the javadocs.  And (of course) **read the javadocs**.

Comment: Note `Math.abs` wont work one time in 2<sup>32</sup>. (And good luck testing that. Hint: Don't use a static mutable object.)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

From the [Java docs for `nextInt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29):

> All 2<sup>32</sup>  possible int values are produced with (approximately) equal probability.

One approach is to use the following transform:

```
s =  rng.nextInt() & Integer.MAX_VALUE; // zero out the sign bit
```

The reason something like this is needed (as opposed to using absolute value or negation) is that `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is too large in absolute value to be turned into a positive integer. That is, due to overflow, `Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE) == Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE == -Integer.MIN_VALUE`. The above transformation preserves the approximately uniform distribution property: if you wrote a generate-and-test loop that just threw away `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and returned the absolute value of everything else, then the positive integers would be twice as likely as zero. By mapping `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to zero, that brings the probability of zero into line with the positive integers.

Here is another approach, which may actually be a tiny bit faster (although I haven't benchmarked it):

```
int s = rng.next(Integer.SIZE - 1); // Integer.SIZE == 32
```

This will generate an integer with 31 random low-order bits (and 0 as the 32<sup>nd</sup> bit, guaranteeing a non-negative value). However (as pointed out in the comment by jjb), since `next(int)` is a `protected` method of `Random`, you'll have to subclass `Random` to expose the method (or to provide a suitable proxy for the method):

```
public class MyRandom extends Random {
    public MyRandom() {}
    public MyRandom(int seed) { super(seed); }

    public int nextNonNegative() {
        return next(Integer.SIZE - 1);
    }
}
```

Another approach is to use a `ByteBuffer` that wraps a 4-byte array. You can then generate a random four bytes (by calling `nextBytes(byte[])`), zero out the sign bit, and then read the value as an `int`. I don't believe this offers any advantage over the above, but I thought I'd just throw it out there. It's basically the same as my first solution (that masks with `Integer.MAX_VALUE`).

In an earlier version of this answer, I suggested using:

```
int s = rng.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

However, according to [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) this will generate integers in the range 0 (inclusive) to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (exclusive). In other words, it won't generate the value `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. In addition, it turns out that `next(int)` is always going to be faster than `nextInt(int)`.

Comment: Random.next() is protected, though, so you can't call it directly. You can subclass Random and expose something like nextPositiveInt() which returns next(31) pretty easily.

Comment: `Integer.SIZE - 1` would be slightly nicer.

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚胡海峰 - Yes, that would make it clearer where the value came from. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: You really gotta ask yourself, when have you ever needed to generate Integer.MAX_VALUE? Your previous answer was perfectly acceptable

Comment: @smac89 - You have a good point, although it does depend on the application. However, if the application needs a truly unbiased non-negative integer generator, then perhaps it should be using something like [`java.security.SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) (a subclass of `java.util.Random`). Besides, I don't like posting "probably good enough" (but wrong) solutions when there are actually correct solutions that are almost as easy to implement.

Comment: Isn't `(-1) >>> 1` just `Integer.MAX_VALUE`? I could just use `rng.nextInt() & Integer.MAX_VALUE`, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Felizett - Well, yes it is, and yes you could. I was thinking about bit patterns and completely missed that. I've updated my code to use this. Thanks.

Comment: If secure random produce Integer.MIN_VALUE, then the result will be 0.
(Integer.MIN_VALUE & Integer.MAX_VALUE) == 0

Comment: @aldok - Correct. As I explained in my answer, this is a good thing because it will mean that 0 will occur (roughly) as often as any positive integer value. (This is true whether using secure random or java.util.Random.)

Answer (score 20):

Since there is an equal chance of positive or negative numbers why not just:

```
Math.abs(rand.nextInt())
```

Nice and easy!

Comment: This won't work. From the [docs for `Math.abs(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs-int-): "Note that if the argument is equal to the value of `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, the most negative representable `int` value, the result is that same value, which is negative."

Comment: Then they should have called the method Math.absExceptIfTheArgumentIsEqualToIntegerMinValueInWhichCaseGoodBloodyLuckToYou(int);

Answer (score 10):

Negative numbers are allowed - maybe you've read of the similar Random method [nextInt( int )](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) which *does* limit the returned values to be zero or greater.

Comment: As mentioned by Ted, `nextInt(Integer.MAXVALUE)` leaves out `Integer.MAXVALUE`, so it is somewhat as good as the obvious `Math.abs` which gets one value wrong (`Integer.MAXVALUE`).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation for java.util.Random:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Are you you trying to get random numbers from 0 to 28? If so, you need to use nextInt(int) as mentioned previously. The seed has no bearing on the range of possible outputs or their relative likelihoods.

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt():

Returns the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value from this random number generator's sequence. The general contract of nextInt is that one int value is pseudorandomly generated and returned. All 2^32 possible int values are produced with (approximately) equal probability.

Just multiply by -1 if the value is negative

Comment: Multiplying by -1 is not a good idea. First, it doesn't work: the negation of `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is `Integer.MIN_VALUE` again (due to overflow), so you can't get rid of all negative numbers that way. Even if it did work, the result would be a non-uniform distribution: zero would have half the probability of any positive integer.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use [Math.random()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) which returns values between 0 and 1

Answer (score 0):

```
int s = rng.nextInt(bound); //bound 29 in this case
```

This will have a bound of **0** to **29**.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to work with numbers that have the possibility of having a negative value you can turn it into a positive value using a conditional declaration automatically by multiplying the value to a negative one. You can also turn a positive into a negative value using this same method.

The examples are below.

```
int a = -5;
a = a < 0? ( a == -2147483648? 0 : -a ) 
           : a;

int b = -2147483648;
b = b < 0? ( b == -2147483648? 0 : -b ) 
           : b;

int c = 12345;
c = c < 0? ( c == -2147483648? 0 : -c ) 
           : c;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for `Integer.MIN_VALUE` because `Integer.MIN_VALUE == -Integer.MIN_VALUE` due to overflow.

Comment: To fix the integer min value problem or max value problem, if you do not mind the number being one number off you can do this,     b = b < 0? b == Integer.MIN_VALUE? (b + 1) * -1 : b * -1 : b;

Comment: If you need the number to be precise, you need a second line to correctly correct the overflow problem. The solution above is only for when you working with a random number and do not mind if the number can be one digit different.

Comment: For OP's case (where 0 is also an allowed value along with all positive integers) the best way to deal with this is to map `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to 0 and to negate all other negative numbers. That way, all non-negative numbers have equal probability of being generated (assuming the underlying generator generates all integers with equal probability). Every positive value can be generated in two ways: either by being produced directly by the PRNG or as the negation of a negative number other than `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. Zero can also be generated two ways: directly and from `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: I do agree with Ted Hopp comment from above, instead of (b + 1) * -1 just change that to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
int randomNumber = new Random().newInt(10);
```

This will return a random number between 0 and 9.