# Select random Java variable? Is this possible

Tags: java, variables, random

Let's say that I have the following set up:

```
private String one = "abc";
private String two = "def";
private String three = "ghi";
```

etc.

I want to write a method that returns a random variable, one of the however many I have declared at the top of the class. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this simple method? Or do it with a `Collection` if you have too many elements.

```
public String getRandomString(){
        Random r = new Random();

        int i = r.nextInt()%3;

        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                return one;
            case 1:
                return two;
            case 2:
                return three;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. (more complicated) use reflection to get the variables in the class, and select one randomaly.
2. (simpler) put them in an array, and choose random index.

Answer (score 0):

You could put them into a list and select a random list element by accessing a list element with a random number (You would of course have to check if the random number is inside the range of the list index).

If you need actual example code, comment on this ;-)

The interesting function you would need is [math.random()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and the most convenient way would be to use array instead of variables and then get a random integer and then use this array's index.

Answer (score 0):

You can put them all in a List and then pick a random number between zero and the list size, and pick that element out of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Put your variables in an array or list and use a random number generator to select a random element in that collection.

Answer (score -1):

I think the accepted solution might return negative values

[Java docs nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29)

- so you might want to use `Math.Abs()`
- or use `r.nextInt(3)`

[java docs nextInt(n)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int))

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827023/java-random-giving-negative-numbers)