# Is it possible to get index out of bound when the index is modulo by the array size?

Tags: java

I have the following code, but sometimes I get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at the specific line with `subject.gets`. I don't see how this could ever happen but it just did. I have some multi-threading going on but this array is local to the function and is not accessed from anywhere else.

```
// Within onCreate
Random random = new Random();

// some where else
List<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<Subject>();

// There is SOME CODE HERE TO ADD ELEMENTS.
// There is SOME CODE HERE TO ADD ELEMENTS.
// There is SOME CODE HERE TO ADD ELEMENTS.
// There is SOME CODE HERE TO ADD ELEMENTS.
// There is SOME CODE HERE TO ADD ELEMENTS.

subjects.get(random.nextInt() % subjects.size())
```

Comment: Yup.  Can you say "negative one"? ;)

Comment: What happens on the very first call when your `ArrayList` is **empty**?

Comment: Will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, no array.

Comment: there are some elements.. even if the list is empty, it would throw `DivideByZeroException` first

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If random.nextInt() returns a negative integer, the result of the mod operation will be negative.

See comments for possible solutions.

Comment: Try random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE); ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827023/java-random-giving-negative-numbers

Comment: Better, just forget the mod ("%") altogether and substitute `random.nextInt(subjects.size())`.  IMHO...

Answer (score 2):

From the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29):

**`nextInt()`** operation will return you

> All 2<sup>32</sup> possible int values

This also include **negative** values and this is the reason the caused you to have Index Out Of Bounds

What you can do to fix this is to use `nextInt(int n)`

**`nextInt(int n)`** operation will return you:

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0
>   (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this
>   random number generator's sequence.

This will **guarantee** you that the random number is a **positive** value.

Comment: _"This will guarantee you that the random number is a positive value."_ -- more accurately, a _non-negative_ value. Zero is not a positive value.