# Java Selection Sort, what is wrong with my code?

Tags: java, selection-sort

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        selectionSort(args);
    }

    private static void printArray(int[] anArray) {
        for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
            System.out.print(anArray[i]);
        }
    }


    public static void selectionSort(String[] args) {

        int i, x = 0;

        int l = 10;
        Random r = new Random(271);
        int array[] = new int[l];
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            array[i] = r.nextInt();
        }

        while (i < l) {

            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                if (array[j] < array[x])
                    x = j;
            }

            i++;
        }
        printArray(array);
    }

}
```

Everything is fine I just cannot print it correctly. When I print I get "-1061221096, -349834974, -1279215928, 1452441141, -367008517, 638966200, -464597014, 1551135748, -446923224, 542496703" which is not correct. Each number should be under 271 I believe.

Comment: What is your input? and why are you passing `args` to `selectionSort` method?

Comment: There is no input, I should only be getting output. I'm suppose to be passing (int[] arr) to the selection sort, but with that I am getting errors.

Comment: `Random` has an internal seed and algorithm which requires you to use a single instance for a group of values, using multiple instances can generate duplicate values or even values in the same order

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827023/java-random-giving-negative-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace this:

```
 Random r = new Random(271);
```

With:

```
 Random r = new Random();
```

And replace  this:

```
 array[i] = r.nextInt();
```

With:

```
 array[i] = r.nextInt(271);
```

You can have output something like this under `271`:

```
  18, 94, 189, 105, 32, 153, 68, 159, 178, 34
```

Comment: Thank you. Please rate this up if you can, I am under 15 karma.

Answer (score 1):

You have the line

```
Random r = new Random(271);
```

Now, every time I've used Random, I've always done it with

```
Random r = new Random();
int rand = r.nextInt(271);
```

That should work as expected.

And just from a code cleanup perspective, you do not need to pass `args[]` to `selectionSort()`. You can simply make the method have no parameters and pass nothing from the main method.

Comment: Thank you, please rate this guy up since I am under 15 karma.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (i < l){
    for(int j=1; j<=i; j++){
        if(array[j] < array[x])
            x = j;
    }

    i++;}
```

this bit of code won't get called because 'i' is equal to 'l' because of the previous loop.
 the 271 is called the  seed and it won't give you arandom numbers less than 271, in order to generate numbers less than 271 you should use `r.next(271)` see the API Documentation [Random API JSE7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int))